# Pub warnings while trying to run bwu_datagrid 0.0.18 and polymer+angular

Tags: dart, polymer, angular-dart, dart-pub, bwu-datagrid

I'm trying to create a simple project with the latest versions of polymer, angular, and bwu_datagrid 0.0.18. I can't get pass the pub get, I get a warning and pub never downloads bwu_datagrid. I need help getting these 3 gems to work in symphony.

pubspec.yaml:
name: angu_poly
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: any
  polymer: any
  bwu_datagrid: "0.0.18"

This is the warning I get:

Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible version constraints on barback:
- polymer 0.10.0-pre.0 depends on version >=0.9.0 <0.13.0
- pub itself depends on version >=0.13.0 <0.15.3

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **

Just in case, I'm on the latest dart editor/sdk:
Dart Editor version 1.7.2.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.7.2

Comment: Try to use a more up-to-date polymer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a specific version constraint to you `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.15.1 <0.16.0'
```

This might lead to follow up errors. Continue accordingly for similar errors.
As last resort you can add dependency overrides to force a package no matter if it fulfills the constraints defined in the other imported packages (use at your own risk though).

```
 dependency_overrides:
   some_package: '=>1.0.0 <1.1.1'
```

Comment: I did, but I'm still getting an error.
my new pubspec.yaml:  
`name: angu_poly  
description: A sample web application  
dependencies:  
  angular: '>=0.14.0 <2.0.0'  
  polymer: '>=0.15.1 <0.16.0'  
  bwu_datagrid: '0.0.18'`  

Warning:  
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible version constraints on args:
- angular 0.14.0 depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0
- polymer 0.15.1 depends on version >=0.11.0 <0.13.0

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **

Comment: I'm sorry, not an error, a warning. I tried doing a dependency override on the BWU datagrid, but no luck. I get a similar warning.  

Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible version constraints on browser:
- angular 0.0.8 depends on version >=0.8.7 <0.9.0
- polymer 0.12.1 depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **

Comment: Your warning misses the package name. You then need to add the package triggering this warning to dependency_overrides as well. It is a bit weird but sometimes when no specific version constraint was set `pub` doesn't use the latest available release, especially when there is no solution that fulfills all version constraints. In this case `angular 0.0.8`. This is the oldest not the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you. I had to override pretty much all dependencies, the project at least compiled, and no more warnings.

Comment: angular, polymer and bwu_datagrid is the complete list of dependencies in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: it was, but now I had to override `args, code_transformers, html5lib, observe, polymer, and angular` to get the project to compile. I forgot to mentioned that we want to use angular 1.0.0+ and polymer 0.15.0+, besides, bwu requires >0.12.1+. I just feel...a bit dirty with this hack, but I understand, that's just the way for now....